# Identify and label repeated data in a series

Tags: r

I'm trying to identify cases in a dataset where a value occurs multiple times in a row, and once this is picked up, a row to the side of the nth occurrence confirms this with '1'.

```
df<-data.frame(user=c(1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4),
               week=c(1,2,3,4,1,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
               updated=c(1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1))
```

In this case, users are performing a task. If the task is performed, '1' appears for that week, if not '0' appears.

Is it possible, in the event that four or more 0s are encountered in a row, that an indicator is mutated into a new column identifying that this sequence has occurred? Something like this:

```
   user week updated warning
1     1    1       1       0
2     1    2       0       0
3     1    3       1       0
4     1    4       1       0
5     2    1       1       0
6     3    1       1       0
7     3    2       1       0
8     3    3       1       0
9     4    1       1       0
10    4    2       1       0
11    4    3       0       0
12    4    4       0       0
13    4    5       0       0
14    4    6       0       1
15    4    7       1       0
16    4    8       1       0
```

Thanks!

Edit:

Apologies and thanks to @akrun for helping with this.

Additional example below, where on the 4th occurring missed entry equalling to '1', the warning column is updated to show the event, where a trigger will run off of that data.

```
df<-data.frame(user=c(1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7),
               week=c(1,2,3,4,1,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
               missed=c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1))
```

```
   user week missed warning
1     1    1      0       0
2     1    2      1       0
3     1    3      0       0
4     1    4      0       0
5     2    1      0       0
6     3    1      0       0
7     3    2      0       0
8     3    3      0       0
9     4    1      0       0
10    4    2      0       0
11    4    3      1       0
12    4    4      1       0
13    4    5      1       0
14    4    6      1       1
15    4    7      0       0
16    4    8      0       0
17    5    1      0       0
18    5    2      1       0
19    5    3      0       0
20    5    4      1       0
21    5    5      0       0
22    5    6      0       0
23    5    7      0       0
24    5    8      0       0
25    6    1      0       0
26    6    2      1       0
27    6    3      1       0
28    6    4      1       0
29    6    5      1       1
30    6    6      1       0
31    6    7      0       0
32    7    1      0       0
33    7    2      0       0
34    7    3      0       0
35    7    4      0       0
36    7    5      1       0
37    7    6      1       0
38    7    7      0       0
39    7    8      1       0
```

Comment: @akrun Apologies - yes, this would be the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to use `rle` to create the warning.  Grouped by 'user', create the 'warning based by checking the`run-length-id` (`rle`) of 'updated', it would give the adjacent similar 'values' and 'lengths' as a `list`, create a logical condition where `values` is 0 and `lengths`is greater than or equal to 4.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
   group_by(user) %>%   
   mutate(warning = with(rle(updated), rep(!values & lengths >= 4, lengths))) %>%
   group_by(grp = rleid(warning), add = TRUE) %>%
   mutate(warning = if(all(warning)) rep(c(0, 1), c(n()-1, 1)) else 0) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 16 x 4
#    user  week updated warning
#   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     1     1       1       0
# 2     1     2       0       0
# 3     1     3       1       0
# 4     1     4       1       0
# 5     2     1       1       0
# 6     3     1       1       0
# 7     3     2       1       0
# 8     3     3       1       0
# 9     4     1       1       0
#10     4     2       1       0
#11     4     3       0       0
#12     4     4       0       0
#13     4     5       0       0
#14     4     6       0       1
#15     4     7       1       0
#16     4     8       1       0
```

---

If we need to flag the group where `any` have greater than 4 0's then

```
df %>%   
    group_by(user) %>%   
    mutate(warning = with(rle(updated), rep(!values & lengths >= 4, lengths)),
           warning = as.integer(any(warning)))
# A tibble: 16 x 4
# Groups:   user [4]
#    user  week updated warning
#   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <int>
# 1     1     1       1       0
# 2     1     2       0       0
# 3     1     3       1       0
# 4     1     4       1       0
# 5     2     1       1       0
# 6     3     1       1       0
# 7     3     2       1       0
# 8     3     3       1       0
# 9     4     1       1       1
#10     4     2       1       1
#11     4     3       0       1
#12     4     4       0       1
#13     4     5       0       1
#14     4     6       0       1
#15     4     7       1       1
#16     4     8       1       1
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks! Is it at all possible at all to have TRUE appear on the fourth occurrence onwards?

Edit: Sorry, just seen the update!

Comment: Sorry - the comment was based on the first version of your submission - you've covered that, by the looks of it! 

When I'm running the above, I'm encountering:

Error in rleid(warning) : could not find function "rleid"

Comment: Thank you! This has really helped and revealed more functions I didn't know about.

Out of curiosity, if the value we're looking for differs from 0, just using the first three lines, excluding the libraries, would changing "!values" to the value we're looking for suffice to perform the match? So say instead of 0, 1 is the repeated match we're looking for.

Comment: @Nodeswitch  You can uses `val <- 2; values == val`  Here the `!values` is kind of saying `values == 0`

Comment: Thanks for all of the help! Is there an easy way to get this to mark up the warning at the four in a row stage? I've tried playing about, but think I might need to add in a for loop?

Comment: @Nodeswitch  I guess the second option would get all the rows for 4 as 1, right?

Comment: Yeah, something like that. I've been trying, but no luck so far.

Comment: @Nodeswitch  I updated the results I got.  Please let me know what you expect

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll keep working at this and see where I get - sorry to keep bothering you!

Ideally, I guess as the 4th occurrence is identified, that's when the warning row is written to, so that the other work can run off of the data at the 4th week in a row. So weeks 1,2 and 3 still have a 0 against them, but when week 4 kicks in meeting the criteria, that's when the 1 goes into the mutated column.

Comment: @Nodeswitch  Can you please edit your post with the new expected output so that it becomes more clear

Answer (score 0):

I followed a different approach. I numbered sequentially the cases where `updated` was 0 for each user and `releid(updated)`. If there's a `4`, that means that there are 4 consecutive homeworks not done. The `warning` is thus created where the new vector is equal to 4.

```
library(data.table)

   df[, 
      warning := {id <- 1:.N; 
                  warning <- as.numeric(id == 4)}, 
      by = .(user, 
             rleid(updated))][, 
                              warning := ifelse(warning == 1 & updated == 0, 1, 0)][is.na(warning),
   warning := 0]
```

### What has been done there

- `warning :=` assigns the result of the sequence that is between the `{}` to `warning`.

Now, inside the sequence:

- `id <- 1:.N` creates a **temporary** variable `id` variable with consecutive numbers for each user and run-length group of `updated` values.
- `warning <- as.numeric(id == 4)` creates a temporary variable with 1 in case id2 is equal to 4 and zero otherwise.

The `by = .(user, rleid(updated))` grouped by both user and run-length values of updated. Of course there were run-length values for `updated == 1`, so we get rid of them by the `ifelse` clause. The final `[is.na(warning), warning := 0]` (notice the chaining) just gets rid of the `NA` values in the resulting variable.

### Data used

```
> dput(df2)
structure(list(user = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), week = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), updated = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

### Speed comparisson

I just compared with @akrun's answer:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.table(user = sample(1:10, 100, TRUE), updated = sample(c(1, 0), 100, TRUE), key = "user")
df[, week := 1:.N, by = user]

akrun <- function(df4){
   df4 %>%
   group_by(user) %>%
   mutate(warning = with(rle(updated), rep(!values & lengths >= 4, lengths))) %>%
   group_by(grp = rleid(warning), add = TRUE) %>%
   mutate(warning = if(all(warning)) rep(c(0, 1), c(n()-1, 1)) else 0) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
}

pavo <- function(df4){
   df4[, warning := {id <- 1:.N; warning <- as.numeric(id == 4)}, by = .(user, rleid(updated))][, warning := ifelse(warning == 1 & updated == 0, 1, 0)][is.na(warning), warning := 0]
}

microbenchmark(akrun(df), pavo(df), times = 100)
Unit: microseconds
      expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
 akrun(df) 1920.278 2144.049 2405.0332 2245.1735 2308.0145 6901.939   100
  pavo(df)  823.193  877.061  978.7166  928.0695  991.5365 4905.450   100
```

Comment: Thanks for another solution! I've been working with this as well as the above and I'm just trying to get one other function out of this and it's to mark the warning on the 4th occurrence, rather than say the 9th if nine weeks have been missed out.

The action that this feeds into works off of the 4th event, while additional beyond is still useful, the 4th is the primary interest.

I'm really new to R and don't quite have my head around it. Would adding in a count to the function work here?

Comment: I think the function I provided will mark exactly the 4th occurrence of consecutive 0s (I may be wrong, but I think Akrun's mark the las of the consecutive 0s, if they're more than 4). I don't quite get why you need a counter... Try studying the simulation data I provided for the speed comparisson, users 3 and 10 have warnings issued, there you can see the differences between both solutions. If you need something additional, let me know

Comment: you're right, it's working exactly as stated. Thank you!